# How to show work items in pipeline test results view?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using a custom [nunit3](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Result-XML-Format) xml report format for Azure DevOps. The test result is working fine, but I was wondering what "Work Items" is supposed to show how to make it work with nunit3:

[image: Work items tab in pipeline test results view]

I was following their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#result-formats-mapping) but I didn't find anything related to that specific "Work Items" tab and how to display information there. How can I get it work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows Work items linked to the test result. You can link work items to a test result with the buttons `Bug` and `Link` on the left.